# Detect object at mouse click location

Tags: psychopy

I have a large number of different image stimuli presented in various locations on screen.

When the participant clicks on a stimulus, I need the name of that stimulus item available for use in the rest of the script.
For example, you can achieve this in E-Prime with the `SlideState.HitTest(x, y)` method, where x and y are mouse coordinates.

The only similar thing I've been able to see in Psychopy is the `mouse.isPressedIn(shape)` method. However because you must supply a specific object as an argument, it seems you would need an `if` clause for each of the stimuli, which seems messy (especially for larger numbers of items)

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm still learning so I might be missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think not. However, if you just add all objects to a list and loop over them, the code will be neat enough.

```py
# List of (pointers to) stimulus objects
shapes = [shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4, shape5]

# Loop over them and check if mouse is pressed on each one of them
for shape in shapes:
    if mouse.isPressedIn(shape):
        # Set this variable to point to the latest pressed shape
        pressed_shape = shape

# Now you can do stuff with this object
pressed_shape.fillColor = 'red'
pressed_shape.draw()
print pressed_shape.name
```

Note that if the mouse clicks at a location where there are two objects, `pressed_shape` is the latest in the list for this solution.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise you could use a list of objects like that!